# To Prove $x'Ax=\mathrm{tr}(xAx')=\mathrm{tr}(Axx')=\mathrm{tr}(xx'A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

To prove,

> $x'Ax=\mathrm{tr}(xAx')=\mathrm{tr}(Axx')=\mathrm{tr}(xx'A)$

where

- $A$ is a square matrix.
- $x'$ is the transpose of $x$.
- For each $x,x'$ are column vector, row vector.

Comment: The last two equalities are a consequence of $\text{tr}$ properties. For the first one just compute the product.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** note that so long as $A$ and $B$ are compatible (that is, $A$ is $m \times n$ and $B$ is $n \times m$), we have trace$(AB) = $ trace$(BA)$, so that
$$
\mathrm{tr}(x'(Ax)) = \mathrm{tr}((Ax)x') \\
\mathrm{tr}((xx')A) = \mathrm{tr}(A(xx'))
$$
All you have to show then is that $x'Ax = \mathrm{tr}(x'Ax)$.

Comment: help to show that xAx'=tr(xAx')

Comment: If x is a column vector, the expression $xAx'$ is not even defined. Could you please adjust the answer?

Comment: @juliohm I think that in the original question, $x$ was a row-vector. I'll change it.

Comment: Thank you @Omnomnomnom, the last paragraph is still outdated, can you please fix the transpose inside the trace?

Answer (score -1):

$$xAx'=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{i}x_{j}a_{ij}=(x_{i}x_{j}) \cdot (a_{ij})=tr(xx'A)$$

Comment: Consider adding explanations to clarify your equations.

Comment: The equation needs a careful matrix calculations.